# Fill in missing values in a row based on another column SPSS syntax?

Tags: spss

I would like to fill missing row values with values from one designated column using spss syntax.

Current Table:(Measure_Table)

| sID | Visit | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 | value_Score | whyMissing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 12 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 12 |  |
| 1 | 3 | 6 | 2 | 5 | 12 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 8 | 2 | 5 | 12 |  |
| 2 | 2 |  |  |  |  | -30 |
| 2 | 3 |  |  |  |  | -10 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 12 |  |
| 3 | 2 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 12 |  |
| 3 | 3 |  |  |  |  | -10 |

I have been trying to use this syntax, but when I do, it runs but the values from whyMissing do not populate into the other columns.
It is important to me to do this with multiple columns because my dataset is larger than what I have shown here.

Desired Outcome Table:(Outcome_Measure_Table)

| sID | Visit | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 | value_Score | whyMissing |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 5 | 12 |  |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 12 |  |
| 1 | 3 | 6 | 2 | 5 | 12 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 8 | 2 | 5 | 12 |  |
| 2 | 2 | -30 | -30 | -30 | -30 | -30 |
| 2 | 3 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 12 |  |
| 3 | 2 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 12 |  |
| 3 | 3 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 | -10 |

This is the syntax that has been able to run, but it will not populate the values when I export to spss. If this was python, I would just use fill na! I am open to other approaches using spss syntax! If I can do this using the interface and past the syntax to use later that is okay too!

My variable view has some of these missing values set as lo -- 0. Would that be getting in the way and how can I bypass?

```
DO REPEAT vr=value_1 TO value_Score.
    IF NOT MISSING(whyMissing) vr=whyMissing.
END REPEAT.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way SPSS handles missing values!!!Thank you so much for your help with the loop above though.

```
*recode the missing values to -9 (or whatever you want) that will be replaced by the whyMissing Variable.
RECODE value_1 TO value_Score (SYSMIS = -9). 

*create a list of variables you want to change. Then run if whyMissing has an error code, replace that variable.

do repeat vr=value_1 to value_Score.
  if whyMissing<0 vr=whyMissing.
end repeat.
EXECUTE.
```

Answer (score 1):

In general the syntax should work. Please check:

1. Did you run `Execute` at the end of the process?
2. Make sure "whyMissing" is a numeric variable.

If these don't help, try running this instead:

```
DO REPEAT vr=value_1 TO value_Score.
    IF MISSING(vr) vr=whyMissing.
END REPEAT.
execute.
```

Comment: Hi, that is a great point to make sure EXECUTE is there! Unfortunately though, no in my data frame this is not working. All of the columns with missing values are otherwise numeric, and the whyMissing column is also numeric, set to scale measure. At some point I will have a column that is in mm/dd/yy Date and nominal scale, too, but do you have any other suggestions on what I might be missing?

Comment: Did my alternative code above not work either? Any error messages?
Try without the loop: `if missing(value_Score) value_Score=whyMissing.`

Comment: no error codes, just not attaching anything! Sorry what do you mean without the loop? I don't know how it would know what variables to choose without the DO REPEAT part. I have tried with a single variable column and it also runs/gives no error, but does not add the whyMissing values.

Comment: Try that line of code - just for one variable and no loop.

Comment: I've tried it after just one column name (and put EXECUTE. at the end), and then I am saving the outfile to a .sav file. Still nothing showing up in my sav file. Perhaps is there something wrong in how I'm outputting this?  Would it help if I call this whole thing after that line a new table name like I would if I was using python?

Comment: After the EXECUTE you should see it in the data, regardless of table name or saving to file of whatever. Is your data different from the example you gave? try posting the original actual syntax maybe something there is bad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256302/discussion-between-eli-k-and-zob).